# Updating retention_time for all user tables in all databases using stored proc

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking to update retention_time from 1 day to 45 days for all 'BASE_TABLE' tables in all databases. I would like to setup stored proc that can be schedule to update base tables. How do I update in all databases. assuming, I'll have to loop though each databases and update table value.

get all databases name : SELECT DATABASE_NAME from Information.schema.databases
get tables name from each database: SELECT TABLE_NAME from information_Schema.tables
get tables from all databases : SHOW TABLES IN ACCOUNT;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE my_storedproc()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
tbl_Query TEXT default 'SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables where TABLE_TYPE = ''BASE_TABLE'' and retention_time <> 1'
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE tbl_Query.table_name SET RETENTION_TIME = 45
END;
$$
;
```

can't run against all the databases.

Comment: Hi - having run the query to get the resultset of the table names you will need to loop through each record using a cursor, dynamically construct the alter statement for each table and execute it. There are plenty of examples of this type of pattern in the documentation e.g. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/resultsets#example-using-a-cursor-with-a-resultset